# ASP.NET5 MVC6 Deploy on Amazon (AWS) - unable to deploy properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy ASP.NET5 MVC6 web application on to Amazon Web Services via **Code Deploy**.

The problem is I have no idea where to place the `appspec.yml` and `before-install.bat` file as the has been a change in the folder structure with ASP.NET5 with the introduction of `wwwroot` folder, and also all of my `.cshtml` files are in the view folder.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- appspec.yml must be placed in the root of an application's source code's directory structure(then you bundle the whole folder).
- You can put your personal script anywhere you want inside you bundle, as long as you give the correct source file directory in side your appspec.yml
- An example of the appspec.yml file can be seen here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html#app-spec-ref-example

Answer (score 0):

Install bower as explained here: http://ruleoftech.com/2015/setting-up-bower-and-gulp-in-windows. Restart the Windows OS. You are done. Before you install bower you have to have Git, Node.js in this precise order. You will install bower from git bash.